# How to make a systemd service stopped before its coredump completion

Tags: systemd, service

We have a systemd service A for our application. And we have a separate program in the same machine to monitor the status of service A. If A is stopped, this monitor program can help redirect the user request to another machine.

However, when the service A core dumped due to a software bug, it may take a long time to dump the memory states. During this period, service A is still considered as alive and the request redirection cannot happen. This affects the responsiveness of our application.

Is there any way to config the service become stopped before the core dump completion? We don't want to disable the core dump for debug usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, the best solution is to improve the monitor program.

If you only check for process name in pid list, then it is not enough.

Instead change monitor program to behave like a client of application A, and do a very quick and simple action in application A to be really sure it is operational, and if not, just redirect immediately users to another application A instance.

Comment: I had assumed the OP was using the systemd status, e.g. `systemctl is-active` or `systemctl is-failed`.  wm8120, can you clarify this?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I didn't know these two commands before. So the monitor program just parsed the output of "systemctl status A" to determine live or dead of service A. When the application is coredump, the output still shows the service is active and running.

Comment: Well, that works out to the same thing - you want `systemctl` to correctly report the status of the service as failed.  (But if it turns out that there is no way to do that, Chaoxiang's answer would serve well as an alternative.)